# Have there been successful non-Asari inter-species relationships?

Tags: mass-effect

In the Mass Effect universe, the Asari are universally compatible for mating with other species, even regardless of gender.  So, it makes sense that they are the most prominent species involved when one tries to come up with a list of inter-species relations.

However, I'm curious to know if there have ever been any well-known, successful inter-species relationships (aside from those Shepard him/herself can commit to) that *do not* involve an Asari.

I do recall, in Mass Effect 2, a Turian was flirting with a Quarian and mentioned a movie that featured a Turian/Quarian relationship.  What I'm looking for is something a little more concrete - a non-fictional (in-universe) long-term romance between two non-Asari races.

Bonus points if the relationship resulted in offspring.

Comment: What's "successful" supposed to mean in the title?  That seems to imply the important part of your question is about mating/offspring, but your question body has that as a mere footnote.

Comment: Successful meaning it's more than just a one-night stand or casual flirting.  Ideally it would entail a marriage or offspring, but not necessarily.

Comment: It seems you are projecting your human morals and expectations on these non-human beings...  What if one or both of the species have no cultural expectation for such relationships?

Comment: @Keen I can't think of an example species from the Mass Effect universe, other than some humans, where it is particularly noted that a one-night stand not intended to result in offspring would constitute a successful relationship.

Answer (score 14):

Tali and Garrus will hook up in Mass Effect 3, if Shepard doesn't have a relationship with either of them.

Joker and EDI will also end up in a relationship if pushed by Shepard in that direction.

Also, the [Fornax](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Fornax) publication implies that there is a subculture interested in interspecies relations.

Comment: Good examples, but these are really a bit too late in the chronology to already be calling them "long term".

Comment: My Tali and Garrus didn't hook up. :(

Comment: @eidylon That just sounds... *wrong*.

Comment: @Iszi Long term would have different meanings depending on the races involved. Salarians live to be 50 or 60 max, where as humans (and Turians?) will hit 1 to 2 centuries. Krogans and Asari, however, can live to be several centuries old, hitting the millennium mark.

Comment: @Xantec Fair point.

Comment: There was a Salarian on the Citadel dating a non-Salarian, but I can't remember what the other species was for certain.

Comment: @phantom42 do you remember which game that was in?

Comment: Sorry, it was in ME3.

Comment: @phantom42 I'll have to look for that next time I am there then.

Comment: Are you talking about the Salarian and his companion who were sitting outside the club where you meet up with Aria? I think was a human woman, who was saying something about how she wanted him to get better shielding or something so he'd be safe. Or he was going to get her better shielding, or something.

Comment: @eidylon That's the one I'm thinking of.

Comment: @eidylon Oh yea. he was injured when Cerberus attacked the Citadel, so she sold her air car to buy him top of the line armor.

Comment: @phantom42 I'd totally forgotten about that one.  Good one, there.

Comment: They aren't in a relationship per say, though it is implied they have feelings for each other.  They only refer to each other as friends

Answer (score 5):

I’m not aware of any long-term inter-species relationship mentioned in the ME universe (games or books), unless it involved an *Asari* or *Shepard*. There is certainly no mention of inter-species offspring, hybrids or *half-bloods*. Again, with the exception of *Asari*.

A (romantic) relationship is certainly not impossible. The comments/answers already mentioned the prime examples from the games. The *Human female* in *ME3* obviously caring for a *Salarian*. Enough to buy him expensive armor to keep him save. Or the *Turian* in *ME2*, trying to convince his *Quarian* friend that she should date someone compatible to her – which means him. And of course *Tali* and *Garrus* if none of them are involved with *Shepard*.

These were not relationships however, but rather the possibility of one.
So it’s not uncommon in the ME universe to find someone of another species attractive. But it’s also not the norm. Most species seem to keep to themselves, with the exception of the *Asari*.
For them, relationships with other species are the norm while relationships with the same species are looked down upon.
*Asari* are special. Not only are they in a sense universally compatible, they are also apparently attractive to most other species. Which is a curiosity in itself.

But even if there was such a relationship, interbreeding would most likely be impossible. It’s not really clear if any of the species have compatible sexual organs.
*Salarians* apparently lay eggs, for example. How would another species fertilize these?
Even if they are compatible in such a way, it’s not said that they could successfully mix their DNA.
Both *Turians* and *Quarians* are dextro-amino based. While they have this in common, it basically only means they can eat the same food. But they might be biologically incompatible otherwise. I believe this is never clearly stated.
And *Krogans* would most assuredly have tried to get offspring like this, if it were possible.

We know that humans can’t interbreed with other species from our planet (at least not that I know of). Otherwise we would have hybrids running around everywhere. So it should be even harder with a species from another planet which might have a totally different genetic makeup.

*Asari* have a unique method of procreation which allows them to circumvent such natural barriers. <s>They extract the genes of the father (can be male or female) and mix them with their own. And they don't even need to have intercourse to do this.</s>
**Edit:** According to the wiki they don't extract the genes but use the *father* as a map to rearange a copy of their own DNA.

This is why *Asari* always give birth to *Asari* and not to hybrids.
And this is why they are in a unique position to have such successful relationships with other species.

Comment: Regarding inter-species mating compatibility: It may be worth noting that Mordin Solus will offer advice regarding physical intimacy between Humans and Turian/Drell/Quarian mates.  While the advice includes information about physiology and "comfortable positions", it does not go so far as to actually say the species are sexually compatible in any physical or genetic manner. (Point being that physical compatibility is not the same as genetic compatibility, and not even actually necessary for "casual" sexual relations.)

Comment: tits on a hanar, anyone? also, in ME3, Mordin tries to convince Eve that Garrus is mate-erial.

Answer (score 2):

Mass Effect Andromeda has an Angaran female and a non-battle-loving Krogan that were implied to be in a relationship until she was physically assaulted and taken back to her home planet. He made her a bracelet and if you can convince her that he'd still care for her regardless, she will go to New Tuchanka to visit him again.

On the Citadel in Andromeda, there are background characters that appear to be in a relationship as well. One couple looks to be an Asari and a Turian.

On the first human settlement while playing soccer with Liam, you guys basically witness an Angaran male and female Asari flirting and it's hinted that they wind up together.

In the consort's office in ME1, there is a Salarian male that's always with a female assistant. He mentions how great she is every time you pass by.

There's also a female human and male Salarian couple on a bench near the consort's office.  I also saw a female human and male Turian couple on a bench, as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities for interspecies relationships but, aside from the asari, children are out of the question due to biological incompatibility. That said, the Reapers managed to create monstrosities by fusing different species together, so with sufficiently high tech it could theoretically be possible, but no Milky Way species has shown it has the technological capacity.

As for those relationships, several are seen in the game: Shepard and Tali, Garrus, or Thane (depending on the sex of Shepard), Tali and Garrus, and in *Mass Effect: Andromeda* there's Ryder and Vetra (human/turian), Avela, or Jaal (human/angaran).

There are some others mentioned in conversations or implied. Interspecies porn is shown to exist, so obviously some people (not just human) clearly aren't put off by the idea.

Answer (score 0):

**There isn't anywhere in the universe that says it can not be done, only that it hasn't actually been tried.**

Y'all are looking at this from a realistic standpoint and not a fantasy standpoint, which is what Mass Effect is, a scientific fantasy. Take Star Trek, for example, humans and Vulcans have two different chemical/bodily makeups but can still reproduce. Really fair since humans in the game haven't been in space for that long at all comparatively. And also take one of Garrus's comments in ME3 into account: if you romance him he talks about having children with you when the war is over, if you make it back.

Comment: "There isn't anywhere in the universe that says it can not be done, only that it hasn't actually been tried." That's exactly what OP is asking: whether it's been tried.

Comment: @ThanatosLetis - Has it been specifically stated that other inter-species relationships haven't been tried? If so, you could improve your answer by citing where and when that was stated.